# Copy all .html files into single file

Tags: linux, command-line, copy

On my Linux server, I need to copy all .html files recursively (from under the currect directory), into a single file, "all.html", for testing purposes.

Could anyone advise on a command that might get me close to doing so?

I just use the 'copy' command, I think, but what parameters do I need to pass?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This will copy all the files into a single HTML file:

```
cat *.html > all.html
```

Comment: @Danny, Thanks for editing and giving it a good shape!

Comment: No problem at all! Keep up the good answers!

Answer (score 1):

He said "recursively" so a simple "cat *.html" won't do. But try this:

```
find -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 cat > all.php.new
```

(beware that you get an error if the output file also ends in *.php as "find" will then match it, too)